# Rewrite GET requests with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm attempting now to rewrite all GET requests of my site with .htaccess, but I didn't find how to do this.
 I want to rewrite all urls like this :

```
index.php?category&cat_id=1
```

to this :

```
index.php/category/cat_id=1
```

Any help please ? 

**Cheers, MrZ**

Comment: Did you not find anything useful from a site search? Am sure this must have been covered pretty much exactly :)

Comment: Without virtualdocumentroot

    # RewriteBase /
    # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]